# I'm getting this error "object ml is not a member of package org.apache.spark"

Tags: apache-spark, sbt, apache-spark-mllib

I am using spark 2.4.4 My sbt file looks like

```
name := "convertor"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.11.12"


libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.4.4"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.4.4"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-mllib" % "2.4.4" % "runtime"
```

But still, I'm getting

```
Error:(6, 25) object ml is not a member of package org.apache.spark
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.OneHotEncoderEstimator
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this library in my sbt file and my problem was solved.

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-mllib" % "2.3.0"
```

Comment: This does not solve the issue, you should use the same version of package, just change your scope(runtime) should work.

Comment: It's a good practice to always use the 'provided' scope for your Spark dependencies. As long as cluster provides Spark classes at runtime, Spark dependencies must be excluded from the assembled JAR.

Comment: I have tried the provided scope of my spark. It didn't work for me.